# How to use local timezone of reply body in ResponseMessage using EWS?

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

```
        MessageBody lvMessageBody = new MessageBody();
        lvMessageBody.BodyType = BodyType.HTML;
        lvMessageBody.Text = myReplyMailBody;
        ResponseMessage lvResponseMessage = ivRawExchangeMail.CreateReply(false);
        lvResponseMessage.BodyPrefix = lvMessageBody;
```

using the above code, the date time field of original message header in the reply text will be set as GMT time.

How can I change it to use my current timezone that the EWS client is running on?
thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32933203/exchange-webservices-create-reply-incorrect-sent-datetime-timezone same resolution

Comment: @GlenScales thank you very much for that, it solves my problem perfectly